# ¿Cómo puedo convertir este SELECT en un JSON, en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
A.Empleado_Codigo,   A.Empleado_Nombre,  A.Empleado_Apellido,  A.Empleado_Sexo, A.Empleado_Cedula,
A.Empleado_Telefono, A.Empleado_Celular, A.Empleado_Direccion, A.Empleado_sueldo,
B.Departamento_Codigo, B.Departamento_Nombre,
C.AFP_Codigo, C.AFP_Nombre,
D.ARS_Codigo, D.ARS_Nombre
FROM empleado A
INNER JOIN departamento B ON A.Departamento_Codigo = B.Departamento_Codigo
INNER JOIN afp          C ON A.AFP_Codigo          = C.AFP_Codigo
INNER JOIN ars          D ON A.ARS_Codigo          = D.ARS_Codigo;
```

Comment: Puedes usar [json_object](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) para obtener las filas como objetos json. SELECT json_object('nombre', nombre, 'tel', tel) FROM persona;
No lo pondrá en un arreglo, ni pondrá comillas, tendrás que hacerlo desde el código.

Comment: Generar el JSON desde MySQL o PHP?

Comment: @alfap  en mysql, te da opciones de tu poder convertir tu select en json, entonces que yo hice cree una vista de mi select y hay mismo convertir en json lo que yo queria, luego ejecute mi query en php y salio perfecto. Chicos por quitar le de su tiempo. pero ya, yo mismo encontré la solución perfecta para lo que quería.

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que esos datos ya los tienes en un array (si no es así, dímelo para incluirlo), entonces solo necesitas hacer esto:

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```